# PostgreSQL false IntegrityError

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

**Couldn't find a solution. I now pass a list of tuples with the information to insert instead of extracting from the other table and the problem went away.**

I am currently writing code that will be editing a table. I have several rows of information to insert but I keep getting `IntegrityError` on the fourth element, regardless of order.

Here is how I create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE segment_speed_live_layer(segment_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                      geom GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, 4326), 
                                      speed INTEGER);
```

Now, the segment_id must match another table, so it is not and cannot be sequencial. Here is the function:

```
def update_layer():
    segment_cursor = connection.cursor()
    segment_query = 'SELECT segment_id, speed FROM segment_speed_live ORDER BY segment_id'
    exists_cursor = connection.cursor()
    exists_query = 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM segment_speed_live_layer WHERE segment_id=%s)'
    insert_cursor = connection.cursor()
    insert_query = """INSERT INTO segment_speed_live_layer(segment_id, geom, speed)
                      SELECT %(segment_id)s, geom_way, %(speed)s
                      FROM other_table
                      WHERE segment_id=%(segment_id)s"""
    update_query = 'UPDATE segment_speed_live_layer SET speed=%(speed)s WHERE segment_id=%(segment_id)s'
    segment_cursor.execute(segment_query)
    for row in segment_cursor:
        segment_id, speed = row
        exists_cursor.execute(exists_query, (segment_id, ))
        exists = exists_cursor.fetchone()[0]
        query = update_query if exists else insert_query
        print(segment_id, speed, exists)
        print(insert_cursor.mogrify(query, {'segment_id': segment_id, 'speed': speed}))
        insert_cursor.execute(query, {'segment_id': segment_id, 'speed': speed})
        print(insert_cursor.statusmessage)
    connection.commit()
```

If I order by speed, it fails on the fifth instead of the fourth element. It seems to fail on lower IDs. This is the testing stage, so I have deleted and recreated the table multiple times, I `KNOW` there is no row in this table with the given ID.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089850/integrityerror-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-django-postgres) and [this blog post](https://www.vlent.nl/weblog/2011/05/06/integrityerror-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint/) but their solutions don't work because my IDs are not assigned sequentially or automatically.

My only thought at the moment is to remove the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, but that is not ideal.

Output for reference:

```
(243, 69, False)
INSERT INTO segment_speed_live_layer(segment_id, geom, speed)
                      SELECT 243, geom_way, 69
                      FROM other_table
                      WHERE other_table.segment_id=243
INSERT 0 1
(680, 9, False)
INSERT INTO segment_speed_live_layer(segment_id, geom, speed)
                      SELECT 680, geom_way, 9
                      FROM other_table
                      WHERE other_table.segment_id=680
INSERT 0 1
(11599, 42, False)
INSERT INTO segment_speed_live_layer(segment_id, geom, speed)
                      SELECT 11599, geom_way, 42
                      FROM other_table
                      WHERE other_table.segment_id=11599
INSERT 0 1
(16399, 40, False)
INSERT INTO segment_speed_live_layer(segment_id, geom, speed)
                      SELECT 16399, geom_way, 40
                      FROM other_table
                      WHERE other_table.segment_id=16399
```

Comment: How many rows are there in `other_table`?

Answer (score 0):

Do it all at once:

```
with u as (
    update segment_speed_live_layer ssll
    set speed = ssl.speed
    from segment_speed_live ssl
    where ssl.segment_id = ssll.segment_id
)
insert into segment_speed_live_layer (segment_id, geom, speed)
select segment_id, geom_way, speed
from
    other_table ot
    cross join
    segment_speed_live ssl
where not exists (
    select 1
    from segment_speed_live_layer
    where segment_id = ssl.segment_id
)
```

Comment: I didn't try this solution because I saw it after I managed to get it working the other way. Thank you anyways, I appreciate the help.